# How to restrict an access to media files in Django on a production environment for anonymous users?

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, http, mod-wsgi

I need to restrict the access to media files in `Django 1.11` on a production environment for anonymous users.

I found this [snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/62/) and it looks like what I want, but I need to use `mod_wsgi` with `apache2`. Is that possible and how could it be accomplished?

Apache config:

```
Alias /static /home/user/myproject/static
<Directory /home/user/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media /home/user/myproject/static
<Directory /home/user/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv python-path=/home/user/myproject
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

Comment: Have you read the Django docs about using Django auth with Apache? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/apache-auth/

Comment: The docs may be wrong on one point though. Where it says ``Require group secret-agents`` should be ``Require wsgi-group secret-agents``.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Nice catch. Care to submit a pull request?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Yes, I have read, but is it possible somehow to get a current user from a django request and make a check without entering login/password?

Comment: You mean for Apache to somehow rely on the cookie being sent and validate it? Never tried the idea, but you might be able to use ``allow_access()`` handler to get access to cookie and then try and determine if user is logged in already. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/access-control-mechanisms.html#host-access-controls